# \hline - width of entire table

Tags: tables

How to set `\hline` to be appropriate for the table?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a3paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\anote}{}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!!]
\tiny
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.45}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  
  r|ccccccccccccccccccccc
}
Fit&&   1&  2&  3&  4&  5&  6&  7&  8&  9&  10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17&\\
\hline
A&  54867,608227&   54867,600478&   54867,597004&   54867,598053&   54867,598004&   54867,597391&   54867,597323&   54867,595745&   54867,59403&    54867,595847&   54867,594425&   54867,595113&   54867,59502&    54868,48386&    54867,591154&   54867,591663&   54867,592885&   \\

\end{tabular*}
\end{table} 

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you make your table so wide and the font size too small? It is very hard to read the numbers.

Comment: I have lots of number and I pretend reading on the computer with zoom. I make it bigger after maybe, but I am confused about hline now.

Comment: I should remove the `\extracolsep` and increase the font size.

Comment: How please?   This doesn't work `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{  
  r|ccccccccccccccccccccc
}`

Comment: You have to use `\linewidth` instead: `landscape` environment doesn't really "understand" `\textwidth`

Comment: @koleygr it does understand it, but (as documented) it maintains it meaning the original portrait width so that page head and foot (which the package keeps in portrait orientation) work correctly.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle ... I just tried to say that this is not using the expected from the op `\textwidth` because from his/her code I understood that by `\textwidth` he/she means the width inside the landscape page (that is the `\linewidth` now)

Comment: @koleygr yes there was nothing wrong with the advice to the OP, just commenting that it was by design (actually it may not have been the best design, given how many people have been confused by it since, I could probably have changed it in the body while locally setting it back in the output routine so page head/foot code worked, but it was all a long time ago:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes, you are right, I already marked your comment as a useful one...  When designing a package, you have in mind that the documentation of your package will be read from the users... and then tex.stackexchange is coming... and people try to just add any way they can imagine and have seen in any similar package/code snippet etc... And your documentation have been read from you and very few people... So, nobody can say that you made a mistake there... but of course I think it would be a useful update too because people is used to think that this length is always the current size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a3paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!!]
\tiny
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.45}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{r|ccccccccccccccccccccc}
Fit&&   1&  2&  3&  4&  5&  6&  7&  8&  9&  10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17&\\
\hline
A&  54867,608227&   54867,600478&   54867,597004&   54867,598053&   54867,598004&   54867,597391&   54867,597323&   54867,595745&   54867,59403&    54867,595847&   54867,594425&   54867,595113&   54867,59502&    54868,48386&    54867,591154&   54867,591663&   54867,592885&   \\

\end{tabular*}
\end{table} 
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

which goes to the right margin

[image]

or this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a3paper]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell,amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!!]
\tiny
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.45}
\begin{tabular}{r|ccccccccccccccccccccc}
Fit&&   1&  2&  3&  4&  5&  6&  7&  8&  9&  10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16& 17&\\
\hline
A&  54867,608227&   54867,600478&   54867,597004&   54867,598053&   54867,598004&   54867,597391&   54867,597323&   54867,595745&   54867,59403&    54867,595847&   54867,594425&   54867,595113&   54867,59502&    54868,48386&    54867,591154&   54867,591663&   54867,592885&   \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

which is better I think

[image]

Comment: It's poor form to use `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{...}` but not set `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` as well.

Comment: using `tabular*` without `\extracolsep` is like using `tabularx` without `X` you are specifying a target width but giving TeX no way to achieve it. If you just have `rcccc` columns you should use `tabular` not `tabular*`

Comment: also why suggest `[h!!]` using two `!` does nothing, and using `h` on its own is usually an error and latex warns about it and changes it to `ht` but `htp` is better still. but in this case the optional argument does nothing at all, as `landscape` does  a `\clearpage` so you get `p` positioning even though you have used the option to prevent `p`

Answer (score 4):

It's not good practice to employ a `tabular*` environment, set its width to `\textwidth` (or some other specific length), but then not let LaTeX adjust the amount of intercolumn whitespace via an `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive, at the start of the second argument of the `tabular*` environment, in order to achieve the desired overall width.

There is no need to shrink the font size all the way to `\tiny` -- `\footnotesize` will do just fine. The difference, in terms of legibility, of shrinking something 20% linearly (aka footnotesize) or 50% linearly (aka tiny) is enormous.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{rotating} % for "sidewaystable" environment
\usepackage[margin=0.25in,a3paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\footnotesize % no need for "\tiny"
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.45}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r *{17}{c}}
Fit& 0&  1&  2&  3&  4& 5&  6&  7&  8&  9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15& 16\\
\hline
A&  
54867,608227&   54867,600478&   54867,597004&   54867,598053&   54867,598004&   
54867,597391&   54867,597323&   54867,595745&   54867,59403 &   54867,595847&   
54867,594425&   54867,595113&   54867,59502 &   54868,48386 &   54867,591154&   
54867,591663&   54867,592885 \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1  "not good practice" could perhaps be better phrased as "it's utterly completely wrong" :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - :-) :-) :-) :-)